# I want to rewrite url through .htaccess rule?

Tags: php

Hi guys actually my url is "http://collection.com/alok/ranjan/dubey.php?pid=12" i want to remove two folder in between this url and my output will be "http://collection.com/dubey.php?pid=12" please help me.
i am writing  as shown below

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^dubey.php?pid=([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ alok/ranjan/dubey.php?pid=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that there is a problem in the regex... it should be

```
^dubey.php?pid=([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ alok/ranjan/dubey.php?pid=$1
```

you forgot to escape the '-' sign which is a special char in regex.

Answer (score 0):

i am using this website for rewriting

http://webtools.live2support.com/misc_rewrite.php

Answer (score 0):

shortest version:)

```
RewriteRule ^dubey.php?pid=([0-9]+)$ alok/rajan/dubey.php?pid=$1
```